# What happens if order of variables in covariance operation is changed?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, covariance

Let $X,Y$ be random variables and let $C$ denote the covariance function.

$$C(X,Y) := E[(X-m_x)(Y-m_y)] = E[XY]-m_xm_y.$$
$$C(Y,X) := E[(Y-m_y)(X-m_x)] = E[YX]-m_ym_x.$$

Setting these equal to eachother $C(X,Y) = C(Y,X)$ gives

$$E[XY] = E[YX].$$

This is only true if $X,Y$ are independent (since then $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]).$ So I conclude that $C(X,Y) = C(Y,X)$ is true if $X,Y$ are independent.

However I read in my textbook that ($X_1, X_2$ being independent)

$$C[X_1,X_1] - 2C[X_1,X_2] - 2C[X_2,X_1] + 4C[X_2,X_2] = V[X_1] + 4V[X_2]$$
doesn't this mean that $C[X_1, X_2] = -C[X_1, X_2]?$.

What's going on here, what's the general rule?

Comment: For any $\omega \in \Omega$, $X(\omega)Y(\omega)=Y(\omega)X(\omega)$ since multiplication is commutative in $\mathbb{R}$, no?

Comment: What? @NapD.Lover

Comment: I am giving you a hint that for any RVs $X, Y$, covariance is commutative: $C(X,Y)=C(Y,X)$, it is even listed as the third property under “covariance of linear combinations” under the “Properties” section of wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance

Comment: @NapD.Lover Mustn't $E[XY] = E[YX]$ always be true then? What about the statement from my textbook? Is my textbook wrong?

Comment: Indeed and it is—proof: $XY=YX$ now take expectations! The LHS, as written, is currently equal to, $V(X_1)-4C(X_1, X_2)+4V(X_2)$ which is $\neq$ to the RHS, unless the middle term is zero, which is true when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. As long as that is assumed, as you (or your book) did, the equation holds.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Ah okay, now I think I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments:
Covariance is commutative:
$C(X,Y)=C(Y,X)$ for *any* random variables $X,Y$.

The quoted equation is correct provided independence is assumed. The middle terms on the LHS will be zero by independence and the outer terms are equal to the terms on the RHS. That is, it just uses the properties: $C(X, X)=V(x)$ and $C(X,Y)=0$ whenever $X,Y$ are independent.